Parsing macros and tikzstyle in Quarto (imagify Lua filter)
I would like to use Quarto and Tikz to create both html and pdf outputs. For this, I am using the filter imagify which converts Tikz pictures for html outputs.
However, I have problems to parse a macro and a tikzstyle, such as:

\newcommand{\env}{\mathcal{E}}
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [->, > = Latex, very thick]

I am going to show the problem with tikzstyle only as I suspect the problems to be similar.

Here is the code that works (provided imagify is installed of course):
test_work.qmd:
---
filters:
  - imagify
imagify:
  header-includes: |
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
format:
  html:
    toc: true
  pdf:
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          \usepackage{tikz}
          \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
          \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
---

![A test](./testFig_work.tex){#fig-testFig}

testFig_work.tex:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %% Define nodes
    \node (N0) at (0, 0) {N0};
    \node[right = of N0] (N1) {N1};

    \draw[->, > = Latex, very thick] (N0) -- (N1);
\end{tikzpicture}


Here is the code that does not work:
test_fail.qmd:
---
filters:
  - imagify
imagify:
  header-includes: |
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \tikzstyle{arrow} = [->, > = Latex, very thick]
format:
  html:
    toc: true
  pdf:
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          \usepackage{tikz}
          \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
          \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
          \tikzstyle{arrow} = [->, > = Latex, very thick]
---

![A test](./testFig_fail.tex){#fig-testFig}

testFig_fail.tex:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %% Define nodes
    \node (N0) at (0, 0) {N0};
    \node[right = of N0] (N1) {N1};

    \draw[arrow] (N0) -- (N1);
\end{tikzpicture}


I gathered in a zip the four files at the issues section of the git repo here.
Does anyone has an idea on how to parse macros and TikZ styles?

Please note that \tikstyle is outdated. Have a look at \tikzset instead

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks, that actually solves the problem!

Glad to hear you were able to solve the problem!

As samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz proposed, replacing \tikzstyle by the new syntax \tikzset worked.
Here is the qmd file with the new yaml header:
---
filters:
  - imagify
imagify:
  header-includes: |
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \tikzset{arrow/.style = {->, > = Latex, very thick}}
format:
  html:
    toc: true
  pdf:
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          \usepackage{tikz}
          \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
          \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
          \tikzset{arrow/.style = {->, > = Latex, very thick}}
---

![A test](./testFig_fail.tex){#fig-testFig}


i.e., use \tikzset{arrow/.style = {->, > = Latex, very thick}}
